# Python средняя относительная ошибка аппроксимации регрессии

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Новичок в питоне и не совсем понимаю как я могу посчитать среднюю относительную ошибку аппроксимации по формуле [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pandas as pd
import math
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv',";",header=None)
X_train = df.drop([16,17],axis=1)
Y_train = df[16]

test_data = pd.read_csv('file2.csv',";",header=None)
X_test = test_data.drop([16,17],axis=1)
Y_test = test_data[16]

normalized_X_train = preprocessing.normalize(X_train)
normalized_X_test = preprocessing.normalize(X_test)

xgb_model = svm.SVR(kernel='linear', C=1000.0)
cl = xgb_model.fit(normalized_X_train,Y_train)
predictions = cl.predict(normalized_X_test)
```

Есть какая-то готовая функция для получения данной ошибки или только циклом? Если циклом, то нужно ли нормализовывать Y_test - реальные значения?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите минимально воспроизводимый пример, а не тучу лишнего кода. После того, как Вы проделаете эти операции, возможно, и вопрос отпадёт

Comment: sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_predicted) / y_test.abs().sum() * 100 - как-то так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

mape = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_predicted) / y_test.abs().sum()
```

Если нужны проценты, то mape надо умножить на 100.

PS Стоит также упомянуть что данная метрика редко используются на практике. Она может вызвать деление на ноль.

Comment: А в этом случае, у нас не получиться в знаменателе Yi в квадрате?

Comment: @KordDEM, не совсем понимаю откуда там может квадрат появиться...

Comment: Да, все верно, извините. Перепутал формулу.

Comment: а может быть подскажите, считаю по данной формуле MAPE и он получается даже при условии умножения на 100% получаются тысячные доли. С чем это может быть связано? И нормальная ли это ситуация для этого параметра?

Comment: @KordDEM, я сейчас в отпуске) Думаю вам лучше задать новый полноценный вопрос со всеми деталями...